# Given a number n and k, how many balanced (height-balanced)binary trees with k leaves are there?

Tags: algorithm

We have n nodes and a k number, How can we calculate (e,g, with dynamic programming) all height-balanced tree with n nodes and k leaves ??

(a height-balanced binary tree is a tree where maximum difference of leaves height is 1.)

Comment: What balance criteria do you mean?

Comment: I mean height-balanced binary tree where maximum difference of nodes height is 1.

Comment: So edit your question and add this important information.

Comment: You need the actual trees, or just their number?

Comment: number with recursive equation

Comment: I made answer for node count case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195634/  Perhaps that approach might be adapted for leaf counts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions/definitions about these trees:

- There are *n* "nodes"; each has either no children, just a left child, just a right child, or both a left child and a right child.
- There are *k* "leaves", meaning nodes with no children.
- If the height of the tree is called *h*, then the nodes with fewer than two children all have depth equal to either *h* or *h*–1. (This is the balancing requirement.)
- A tree is fully defined by its structure (which nodes have no children vs. left children vs. right children vs. both left and right children).

Given the above, the tree consists of a full binary tree of height *h*–1 **plus** one or more leaf nodes in the bottom level. The total number of leaves is equal to the number of leaves that we add, plus the number of nodes in the previous level that we don't add any children to.

So, at a high level, the algorithm is as follows:

- Compute how many nodes are in the bottom level, and how many are in the level above that. (This depends only on *n*; for example, a full binary tree of height 6 has 2<sup>6+1</sup>–1 = 127 nodes, so if *n* = 130, then the bottom level has 3 nodes, and the second-to-bottom level has 64 nodes.)
- Compute how many nodes in the second-to-bottom level have no children (which is *k* minus the number of nodes on the bottom level), and how many of the rest have one child vs. two children (using the previously-obtained results).
- The total number of possible trees can then be determined by combinatorics. Specifically, it is the product of these three values:

  - the number of ways to choose, from the nodes on the second-to-bottom row, which ones have no children: (nodes in the second-to-bottom level) nCr (nodes in the second-to-bottom level with no children)
  - the number of ways to choose, from the remaining nodes on the second-to-bottom row, which ones have one child: (nodes in the second-to-bottom level with one or two children) nCr (nodes in the second-to-bottom level with one child)
  - the number of ways to choose, from the nodes on the second-to-bottom row with one child, which ones have left-children vs. which ones have right-children: 2<sup>(nodes in the second-to-bottom level with one child)</sup>

While implementing this, be sure to take into account the possibility that there are *no* trees with given values of *n* and *k*; for any given *n*, only a certain range of values of *k* is actually possible for a tree satisfying the above constraints. If *k* is outside that range, then the implementation needs to return 0.

Comment: your solution is not correct. how we can "Compute how many nodes are in the bottom level, and how many are in the level above that" in step one, it is not depend on your n. you should consider balanced tree. how do you compute this step ???

Comment: @M2E67: Re: "your solution is not correct": Please provide evidence of this. (Note that your problem description was a bit vague, so I had to make my best guess as to what you meant. If you meant something a bit different, then please write your problem more explicitly.)

Comment: "the tree consists of a full binary tree of height h–1 plus one or more leaf nodes in the bottom level." - this statement is wrong. See this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#/media/File:AVL-tree-wBalance_K.svg

Comment: @VaibhavMaheshwari: You seem to have misunderstood something. My answer is not about AVL trees. Your image is incompatible with the third "assumption/definition" I listed.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Actually, I was searching for something similar to AVL trees and read it that way. Didn't read the question correctly.

Comment: @VaibhavMaheshwari: No worries. I'm actually not sure that you misread the question; this answer reflects my understanding of what the OP meant, but I'm not sure of my understanding. It seems possible that the OP actually meant AVL trees (though in that case I'm not sure why (s)he wouldn't just say so).